# App center vs. App center system-wise

Tags: appcenter

So in the early access rc for eOS6, in the app center there are two drop-down choices to download apps, app center vs. app center system-wise. Can someone explain to me what do these mean?

Answer (score 1):

`System-wide` means that the installed app will be available for all users as opposed to `user` which would make an application available only to the current user.